# Adding a macOS app to the list of accessibility in privacy system preferences

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, keyevent, privacy

I am working on a macOS app that is a background app and so I would like to perform a particular function when a keyboard key is pressed. I read from the apple documentation that **addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler: )** must be used. And also to use this, accessibility must be enabled.
I checked for accessibility with **AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions** and the functionality has been implemented and it works right.
I give an alert to the user asking to enable accessibility and if the user agrees, the accessibility in the privacy system preferences window opens.
Now, the issue I face is the **app is not present in the accessibility list** and so the **user has to add the app manually into the list**.
Is there any way to **programmatically(SWIFT) add the app to the accessibility list?**

Answer (score -1):

Hy MaraV932,

this is very easy,
only what you should do is to add this:

```
<key>NSUserInterfaceAccessibility</key>
<dict>
    <key>Enabled</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

to your `<AppName>.entitlements` file then rebuild your project again, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSUserInterfaceAccessibility</key>
<dict>
    <key>Enabled</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then add this function to your project

```
import Foundation

func isAccessibilityEnabled() -> Bool {
    let options: NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as NSString: true]
    return AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
}
```

In the `.onAppear` function call the function, like this:

```swift
Text("some text")
    .onAppear {
        isAccessibilityEnabled()
    }
```

it should now open a dialog to go to the settings to give the app accessibility access, the app should now display in the list.

Comment: didn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/q/76807911/4423545

Comment: @Khalil Khalil: this key does not seem to be documented. Not findable in Apple Documentation or via Google. Can you point to any reference documentation or example?